# Do we need "micro-payment channels" for IOTA similar to Bitcoin or Ethereum?

Tags: flash-channel, microtransaction, fees

Since IOTA transactions are ***free of fee***, so ***do we need*** to setup a "micro-payment channels" similar to what we have in Bitcoin? (For example "[The bitcoin lightning network](https://www.weusecoins.com/assets/pdf/library/Lightning%20Network%20Whitepaper.pdf)" or "[Duplex Micropayment Channels](https://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/file/716b955c130e6c703fac336ea17b1670/duplex-micropayment-channels.pdf)")

***Because we usually use such payment channels to save transactions fee.***

***So, why do we need to use ex. flash channel in IOTA ? Only to accelerate transactions ?***

I am right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, one reason is to accelerate transactions i.e. make almost **instant transactions** because **no proof of work** is required but they have a second advantage: **offline transactions** because one doesn't need to be connected to any full nodes to send Iotas via Flash Channels.

One use case for Flash Channels are for example [EV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_vehicle) charging stations because they allow you to pay while charging and not in advance.